# Typescript: Union type `string | undefined` and ternary

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator, union-types

I have a question about the code below, I am not sure to understand why the second return is valid. Doesn't the first return do the same kind of check ?

```js
type User = {
  email: string
  firstName?: string
  lastName?: string
  first_name?: string
  last_name?: string
} & ({ first_name: string } | { firstName: string }) &
  ({ last_name: string } | { lastName: string })

const formatUserFullName = (firsname: string, lastname: string): string => `${firsname} ${lastname}`

export const computeUserFullName = (member: User): string => {
  let { firstName, lastName } = member
  if (!firstName) {
    firstName = member.first_name
  }
  if (!lastName) {
    lastName = member.last_name
  }

  // This throw an error about firstName and lastName that can be undefined and are not accepted by my method
  return !firstName && !lastName
    ? member.email
    : formatUserFullName(firstName, lastName)

  // This works
  return !!firstName && !!lastName
    ? formatUserFullName(firstName, lastName)
    : member.email
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The opposite of `!!firstName && !!lastName` is `!(!!firstName && !!lastName)` which [simplifies to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!firstName || !lastName`

Comment: What Vlaz said!

Comment: In `!firstName && !lastName`, `firstName` could be `'mark'`, and `lastName` could be undefined and it would go to `formatUserFullName('mark', undefined)`. Since you've defined `formatUserFullName` as taking two `string`s, not `string | undefined`, it rightfully rejects that.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, it was that simple... Thank you for your responses !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't the first return do the same kind of check ?

No, it does not. The one that works uses

```
firstName && lastName
```

(simplified, since in boolean algebra `!!x = x`)

and the inverse of that expression is

```
!(firstName && lastName)
```

Which according to [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `not (A and B) = not A or not B` converts to:

```
!firstName || !lastName
```

It is easy to check the truth tables for these and see which is the correct operation that produces the opposite results:

| firstName | lastName | firstName && lastName | !firstName || !lastName | !firstName && !lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Truthy | Truthy | Truthy | Falsy | Falsy |
| Truthy | Falsy | Falsy | Truthy | Falsy |
| Falsy | Truthy | Falsy | Truthy | Falsy |
| Falsy | Falsy | Falsy | Truthy | Truthy |

To transition from boolean algebra back to code, the **Falsy** value could just be `undefined` in the case when the property is missing from the `member` object.

This means that, for example, `firstName` or `lastName` is `undefined`, then the check you do returns the opposite of what you want:

```js
const check1 = (firstName, lastName) => {
  // This works
  return !!firstName && !!lastName
}
const check2 = (firstName, lastName) => {
   // This throw an error about firstName and lastName that can be undefined and are not accepted by my method
 return !firstName && !lastName
}
console.log(
  check1("Fred", undefined),  //false - correct
  !check1("Fred", undefined), //true - expected
  check2("Fred", undefined)   //false - wrong
);
console.log(
  check1(undefined, "Bloggs"), //false - correct
  !check1(undefined, "Bloggs"),//true - expected
  check2(undefined, "Bloggs")  //false - wrong
);
```

Which shows that TypeScript correctly found a bug in your code. It works correctly when using

```typescript
return !firstName || !lastName
    ? member.email
    : formatUserFullName(firstName, lastName)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=24&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClCBbAQwEsAbALijmESIDsBzbKAMyMSoDkC8IB+CqjQZMSBTtz4DqdRjlbtgAfVoT+lacJyiqy1VKGMAvlABkUABToWbHSp76ZUYwB8M1hV3vqDTgJSmmSyhtJTsIBwYnKFcrEM9w70dDX0xMAGMAe1oqFgzEQmB4JAAxAFcSEnjUC3k4MIj6ABpgsWB6xIZfBtQAPigAAwASdFqw42GQsf7UiAAPMDzgKEzspcy8MFLgCCLEMoqqtHMePAAjJApdro76XowRCCWrWuB45riJKLQT88QmImYFgAhC94v4sDg5DZXp9vvhfgA6F66HhMQz-QHmIEfHjgphaVqHKA-JAIkIoiBo1I4AD0NKgABUABZEOBQWgZADuUE5eQA1nAmIhHqVELQoCDoVVnK5sYSJPioLxifDSfhiCRFRRmHkCrt9pUJOZQRJ3vLcZh0UA)